# How to rewrite $\textit{Bessel-Kelvin}$ such that it is implementable in computer program?

Tags: bessel-functions

Winding ac resistance is given by

$R_{ac}=R_{dc}\cdot\frac{\gamma}{2}\cdot [ \frac{ber_0(\gamma)\cdot bei_1(\gamma)  - ber_0(\gamma)\cdot ber_1(\gamma)}{ber_1(\gamma)^2+bei_1(\gamma)^2}    -   \frac{bei_0(\gamma)\cdot ber_1(\gamma)  - bei_0(\gamma)\cdot bei_1(\gamma)}{ber_1(\gamma)^2+bei_1(\gamma)^2} ]$

which consists of $\textit{Bessel-Kelvin}$ functions and I would like to know how I can solve this so that I can implement this in MATLAB or any other program.

**EDIT**:
Power series expansion of Bessel function (First kind positive order):

$J_v(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(x/2)^{v+2k}}{k!\zeta(v+k+1)}$

No idea how to simplify it, I only want to be able to implement it into computer software.

Comment: Why don't you simplify the expression in the bracket?

Comment: That's my question, I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the function, but typical strategy (for me, when I have something like this is to compute each component as a variable, then return something like A*B*(C*D/E*F + G*H/I*J), just be careful about order of operations